# Best Practices for Renaming Program Files?

Tags: windows-7

I do a lot of bouncing between cygwin and Windows command shell, and I always end up in pain from miscellaneous space and/or parenthesis issues (MS you really killed me with "Program Files (x86)"). What's the best/easiest way to just rename these directories to drop the spaces and/or parens?

Comment: My choice would be an underscore to replace any non-alphanumeric characters.

Comment: why do you 'cygwin' around in $PROGRAMFILES anyway?

Comment: You can't rename these directories without getting into heaps of trouble. Some variant of heavyd's answer is probably the way to go.

Comment: i access %PROGRAM FILES% because that's how i get to my programs. Not sure what the alternative is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Symbolic links in cygwin can help fix this:

```
ln -s /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\) /ProgramFilesx86
```

Answer (score 3):

Learn to use Windows "short names".
For example, the short name for "Program Files" is PROGRA~1 and "Documents and Settings" is DOCUME~1.

Type "`dir /x`" to see short names.

Comment: what an interesting idea... so I could go into my PATH and update these all?

Comment: yes, that is what I have done.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows you could create a softlink to the directory, using a desired short name, which in reality points to the real destination. Windows 7, and I think Vista, has this capability built in. Similar functionality can be added to XP via the Junction software.

Comment: Can be *accessed in* XP via the Junction software. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx